# Attribute 'for' of label error

Tags: jsf, websphere

I am using MyFaces JSF 2.0 - IBM implementation on WebSphere V8.0. In system out message I am noticing below error only after successful login by user.

```
HtmlLabelRend W   Attribute 'for' of label component with id j_id1610532955_33b1d0aa is not defined
```

I do not have any field named "id". Any pointer to resolve this issue will be useful

Comment: You are probably using `h:outputLabel`, and it's `for` attribute points to a component that doesn't exists. The value of the `for` attribute must be the ID of an existing component, the component you want to label.

Comment: Thanks @RinaldoPJr - this resolved the issue. If you add this as answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `h:outputLabel` is used for labeling input components. It renders a `label` [html tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp).

You are probably using `h:outputLabel`, and it's `for` attribute points to a component that doesn't exists.

The value of the `for` attribute must be the ID of an existing component, that is, the component you want to label. For example:

```
<h:outputLabel for="username" />
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{bean.username}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

> *I do not have any field named "id".*

You seem to be abusing a `<h:outputLabel>` for something else than [labeling input elements](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/label/).

If you want to show pure text, use `<h:outputText>` instead.

If you're using Facelets as view technology and you don't need to set any additional attributes on the output text, then you can even just use EL in template text instead.